# Lightning Node hardware

Tags: nodes

Will I, or anybody have more capabilities with a Lightning Node, that is CPU or GPU Powered?

For instances a more powerful computer vs Raspberry Pi’s

Comment: I think you mean, what is the best hardware where you can run the lightning node. Well, if you mean that, I think you don't need the GPU power because the lightning network doesn't work such as Bitcoin. You can read the reference implementation of lightning here https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc/blob/master/00-introduction.md

Answer (score 3):

> **Will I, or anybody have more capabilities with a Lightning Node, that is CPU or GPU Powered?**

No

I believe all implementations of Lightning nodes are CPU based. There doesn't seem to be any need for using GPUs to accellerate any mathematical computations.

I assume we exclude budget microcontrollers from what you mean by "CPUs". We are talking about CPUs found in general purpose computers on the market today that have at least some usefulness as typical light-usage desktop computing devices.

> **For instances a more powerful computer vs Raspberry Pi**

It seems you can run a Lightning network on a Raspberry Pi 3.

Having a faster CPU doesn't give you any specific financial advantage over other people. It just makes the computer more responsive in interactive use.

A faster CPU might enable your lightning node to run more channels (or something) or act as a gateway for a higher volume of traffic - but as I understand it, the financial benefits are absolutely insignificant.

I'm not certain what sorts of capabilities you are concerned about but it seems that a typical usage of a lightning node is not especially CPU intensive.

---

References:

- [Bitcoin Lightning Node on Raspberry Pi](https://medium.com/coinmonks/bitcoin-lightning-network-run-your-node-at-home-for-fun-and-no-profit-da5b61be2ba9)